# Find distance between two figures

Tags: geometry, puzzle

[image]

I was trying on this problem. All information is in picture. The aim is to find $AB$. It looks very simple problem. I spent more than one hour to solve it but I can't. It looks simple,but equation are not independent.

Is there any constructive hint? (or solving method)

Comment: Is there no other information provided with this diagram?  Anything (for instance) about the diagonals?

Answer (score 9):

There's not enough information in that picture to find any horizontal distance. If you have a situation that matches the information there, you can stretch or shrink it horizontally by any (nonzero) factor you'd like, and it would *still* match the information.

Comment: In fact you can even derive the height of the middle pole from the height of the cacti.

Comment: @Improve: Yes, except that does not help. The pole height will be $\frac{ab}{a+b}$, so the measurements in the diagram are actually consistent.

Comment: @Improve Indeed, let the middle pole cross $AB$ at $M$. Then $\frac{BM}{AB}=\frac{h}{70}$ and $\frac{AM}{AB}=\frac{h}{175}$, so $\frac{h}{70}+\frac{h}{175}=1$, so $h=50$.

Comment: Of course it does not help, it just adds to the belief that there is something unstated/wrong about the information given in the problem.

Comment: There were multiple choice :$$AB=200\\AB=150\\AB=100\\AB=50\\$$is this help ?

Comment: @Khosrotash: No, doesn't help. Each of those answers is consistent with everything in the diagram.

Comment: Is this problem has a special name ? or something like that ?!

Comment: @Khosrotash: Henning's answer simply says that if you stretch the image horizontally, clearly none of the vertical heights change, but straight lines remain straight lines, so if there is any solution at all then all distances for AB are also possible.

Comment: I think the problem is simply to make you think or to confound as it looks like one can find a single answer but in reality you can't conclude *anything*.  Where is this problem from?